# Edit closing text in Email footer

Tags: email, email-templates, css, rwd-theme, scss

I would like to remove text-align:center in the closing text of email footers.

However, when I open \skin\frontend\rwd\default\scss\email-inline.scss, i see the following disclaimer:

> Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to
>   newer versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for
>   your needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more
>   information.

Not the most useful disclaimer in the world.  How do I make this tiny formatting change and retain it after future updates?

Answer (score 1):

This disclaimer is shown because you're trying to edit the default theme (note that you're in a subdirectory of `/frontend/**rwd**/default`. This theme will be updated when Magento is updated and therefore the file will be reset eventually and your changes will be lost.

To override this style, create your own theme (or copy an existing one like rwd) and change the file there.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Wouldn't this also be problematic?  When a Magento update is released, it will also come with an updated skin.  You want to get the benefit of the updates while retaining customizations, right?

Comment: This is correct, but it's a general problem. If there's an update to Magento, you should update your themes and modules accordingly. This is the job of the developer (you). The warning just wants you to not edit it so that rwd will always work unconditionally. If you mess with files in /rwd/*, this can't be guaranteed anymore. Also, some themes rely on rwd, so there's a benefit in being able to say that rwd is always okay and not broken / changed / behaving unexpectedly. Makes more sense now?

Comment: Sure, but editing that file didn't get rid of the centering.

Comment: Well, you'll have to enable your theme (the one you copied and only edited one file) and use it in your shop. If you got the correct file, this will work. You can also test the effect by editing the forbidden file ( ;) ). If this works, just copy the edit over to your theme and revert your changes in the forbidden file.

Comment: No, I'm not going the child theme route.  I just edited the file in the rwd directory, but it didn't have any effect on the formatting of the emails.

Comment: Ok, then you need to aware that you might lose your changes on the next update, but you know that by now. In this case though, you're most likely (99%) using the wrong file. Please write a new question for this though, this was about the hint that you shouldn't edit rwd files

Comment: It's not that important, so I'll let this issue go for now.  I have more important things to figure out about Magento first.

Comment: Sure, good luck with your project @KnocksX